# "Особый" и "особенный"

Tags: лексика

Интуитивно чувствую разницу между понятиями "особый" и "особенный", но сформулировать словами не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба слова многозначные. В одном из значений они совпадают: 'не похожий на других, не такой, как все; необычный, своеобразный'. В других же значениях есть разница.

Слово **особый** может иметь значения:

- 'большой, заметный, значительный', например: *Ударить с особой силой;*
- 'отдельный, не общий': *особое помещение;*
- 'имеющий специальное назначение': *особая комиссия, особое совещание.*

Слово **особенный** может иметь такие значения:

- 'необыкновенный, исключительный в каком-либо отношении': *особенный день, особенное явление;*
- 'отличающийся от других по степени проявления; большой, значительный': *особенное волнение, особенное удовольствие.*

Answer (score 0):

Особый - относящийся к "особям" , т.е. к какой-то определенной группе вещей, понятий или предметов.
Особенный - необычный, отличающийся от всех остальных в конкретной  категории.
Например, - "этот случай был особый в череде дней, так как в этот день поведение дельфинов было особенным и непривычным".

Comment: А "особи" у вас дельфины или дни?

Comment: Особи - это несколько устаревшее слово, обозначавшее ранее любую группу однородных вещей одушевленных или нет. Мной это слово приведено, чтобы показать, что особый и особи - прямые однокоренные слова, а слово, относящееся к группе однородных вещей(понятий), в данном предложении - СЛУЧАЙ, который был ОСОБЫМ.