# Особенное спасибо — ошибка?

Tags: орфография

Будет считаться ошибкой, если я написала «особенное спасибо Алексею за работу», а не «особое спасибо...»?

Comment: О различии между особым и особенным см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, кто как посчитает, но на мой взгляд, это не совсем точное выражение, поскольку "*особенным*" было бы спасибо, выраженное в оригинальной *форме*. А **особое** (= *отдельное* - тому, кого хочется выделить после благодарности, выраженной другим) спасибо было бы убедительнее -  в сочетании с уточнением, "за какую именно" работу, чем вклад Алексея выделяется. В форме наречия (**особенно** Алексея) однокоренное слово можно употребить с несколько другим смыслом: *в большей степени* (чем других) или *в первую очередь, прежде всего* хочется поблагодарить того-то.